# Ambiguity between Static and Instance Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, oop

I have two items in my class: One is a public property, and the other is a static method that takes a parameter.

I really do not understand why Visual Studio 2010 is unable to see the difference between these two items.

Could someone explain this one to me?

Here is the code:

```
public bool IsShipped {
  get {
    #region ' Test Code '
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TrailerNo) || (TruckDate != Global.NODATE)) {
      return true;
    }
    #endregion
    return false;
  }
}

public static bool IsShipped(string boxNumber) {
  var array = GetCrate(boxNumber);
  if (array != null) {
    foreach (var item in array) {
      if (item.IsShipped) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Here is the error:

> Error 1   Ambiguity between 'AcpClasses.AcpPackNShip.IsShipped' and 'AcpClasses.AcpPackNShip.IsShipped(string)'   C:\Users\cp-jpool\My Projects\VS\Live\Common\Classes\AcpPackShip.cs 242 20  CoilPC

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's possible to refer to a method as a delegate, not just by calling it.  For example, the following could would be valid use of the method:

```
Func<string, bool> myFunction = item.IsShipped;
```

Given that the method doesn't need to be actually called with parenthesis, there is no way of determining if `item.IsShipped` is supposed to refer to the method group for `IsShipped` or to be the property `IsShipped`.

Even if it were *allowed*, it would be a point likely to result in confusion.  It would be preferable from a code maintenance perspective to have different names for the property/method, even if the compiler were somehow smart enough to know which one to use when (or worse, if it just picked one arbitrarily).

Answer (score 8):

You can overload methods with different signatures, but you can't have a field or property with the same name as a method.

That's because the raw name of a method evaluates to a method group, used when creating a delegate.

This snippet of code clearly shows the problem:

```
bool b = item.IsShipped;
Func<string, bool> d = item.IsShipped;
```